# Room database - Access data from second activity

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I apologize if this is a duplicate.
I'm currently working on a ToDo app and I'm using the Room database library to display a list of items using a RecyclerView. From the main activity, I am able to access the information from the database using the adapter. No problem here.

The thing is that when I press on one of the items, I want to open a DetailActivity where the user can modify the ToDo. Currently I'm getting the desired information using putExtra and hasExtra:

MainActivity

```
private void initializeAdapterForRecyclerView(){
    mAdapter = new ToDoAdapter(new ToDoAdapter.ToDoClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onToDoClick(int clickedItemIndex) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(ToDoActivity.this, EditorActivity.class);
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "This is " + mAdapter.getToDoPosition(clickedItemIndex).getTitle());
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, String.valueOf(clickedItemIndex));
            intent.putExtra("existingTitle", mAdapter.getToDoPosition(clickedItemIndex).getTitle());
            intent.putExtra("modifiedTitle", mAdapter.getToDoPosition(clickedItemIndex).getDisplayTitle());
            intent.putExtra("existingDescription", mAdapter.getToDoPosition(clickedItemIndex).getDescription());

            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    mToDoList.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}
```

DetailActivity

```
private void getExistingToDoContent() {
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if (intent.hasExtra("existingTitle")) {
        String displayTitle = intent.getStringExtra("modifiedTitle");
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Getting the title: " + displayTitle);
        mTitleEditText.setText(displayTitle);

        String existingDescription = intent.getStringExtra("existingDescription");
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Getting the description: " + existingDescription);
        mDescriptionEditText.setText(existingDescription);
    }
}
```

The issue comes when I want to delete the item from the DetailActivity as I want to do this with the the ViewModel class.

ToDoViewModel

```
public void delete(ToDo toDo){
    mRepository.delete(toDo);
}
```

ToDoRepository

```
    public void delete(ToDo todo){
    new deleteAsyncTask(mToDoDao).execute(todo);
}

private static class deleteAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<ToDo, Void, Void> {

    private ToDoDao mAsyncToDoDao;

    deleteAsyncTask(ToDoDao dao){
        mAsyncToDoDao = dao;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(ToDo... toDos) {
        mAsyncToDoDao.deleteToDo(toDos[0]);
        return null;
    }
}
```

}

So my question is, is it possible to access the database entry of the clicked item from the DetailActivity to populate the fields and delete / update the entry using the methods from the ViewModel activity? (other than using putExtra / hasExtra)

Thank you